# how to find arguments mean in dtrace

Tags: linux, performance, dtrace

the code

```
dtrace -n 'syscall::read:entry /execname != "dtrace"/ { @reads[execname, fds[arg0].fi_pathname] = count(); }'
   dtrace: description 'syscall::read:entry ' matched 1 probe
   ^C
   bash            /proc/1709/psinfo                                                 1
   loader          /zp/space/f2                                                      1
   nscd            /etc/user_attr                                                    1
   bash            /export/home/mauroj/.bash_history                                 2
   loader          /zp/space/f3                                                      2
   nscd            /etc/group                                                        2
   su              /etc/default/su                                                   8
   su              /devices/pseudo/sy@0:tty                                          9
   bash            /dev/pts/5                                                       66
   Xorg            /devices/pseudo/conskbd@0:kbd                                   152
   gnome-terminal  /devices/pseudo/clone@0:ptm                                     254
```

the dtrace code `fds[arg0].fi_pathname`

how to see the dtrace call arguments what's mean,i try to use

```
trace -lv 'syscall:fds:read:entry' |head
   ID   PROVIDER            MODULE                          FUNCTION NAME
    1     dtrace                                                     BEGIN

    Probe Description Attributes
        Identifier Names: Stable
        Data Semantics:   Stable
        Dependency Class: Common

    Argument Attributes
        Identifier Names: Stable
```

but can't find the arguments?
how see these argements mean?
eg `fds[arg0].fi_pathname`

give another example:

```
 dtrace -n 'io:::start { @bytes = quantize(args[0]->b_bcount); }'
```

how to known the args[0]->b_count meant syscall bytes

Comment: Since your question is about DTrace, which exists on various platforms, you should delete the "linux" tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28556/gkzlf.html#gkzjn) explains, for the syscall provider's entry probes, `arg0`, `arg1` etc. are the system call's arguments themselves.  For `syscall::read:entry`, then, looking at the `read(2)` man page shows

```
 ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);
```

and so `arg0` is the value of `fildes`.

Unfortunately, `fds[]` doesn't appear to be described in the official documentation.  `fds[]` is something, similar to a subroutine, that DTrace provides to [translate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28556/gkylj.html#scrolltoc) a file descriptor into a [`fileinfo_t`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28556/gkzzf.html#gkzzw).  The `fileinfo_t` is a stable structure that provides useful information about a file without exposing the implementation details to the user.

The documentation for the [io provider](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28556/gkzzf.html#scrolltoc) states that, for `io:::start`, `args[0]` is a pointer to a `struct buf`.  This is another documentation bug:  it's actually a pointer to a `struct bufinfo`, which is described on the same page.