# Why is the syscall read argument null?

Tags: dtrace

The dtrace

```
dtrace -n 'syscall::read:entry { @[fds[arg0].fi_fs] = count(); }'
```

I want to find the argument read fds

```
trace -lvn 'syscall::*read*:entry'


 933    syscall                                       read_nocancel entry

    Probe Description Attributes
        Identifier Names: Private
        Data Semantics:   Private
        Dependency Class: ISA

    Argument Attributes
        Identifier Names: Private
        Data Semantics:   Private
        Dependency Class: ISA

    Argument Types
        None

  963    syscall                                      readv_nocancel entry

    Probe Description Attributes
        Identifier Names: Private
        Data Semantics:   Private
        Dependency Class: ISA

    Argument Attributes
        Identifier Names: Private
        Data Semantics:   Private
        Dependency Class: ISA

    Argument Types
        None

  969    syscall                                      pread_nocancel entry

    Probe Description Attributes
        Identifier Names: Private
        Data Semantics:   Private
        Dependency Class: ISA

    Argument Attributes
        Identifier Names: Private
        Data Semantics:   Private
        Dependency Class: ISA

    Argument Types
         None
```

But the argument is None. How to find the arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the **meaning** of an argument with the **type** of an argument.

The **meaning** of an argument depends on the provider.  If you want to learn about `syscall:::` probes then you need to consult the documentation for the [syscall provider](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28556/gkzlf.html#scrolltoc), which says

> **Arguments**
>
> For entry probes, the arguments (`arg0` .. `argn`) are the arguments to
>   the system call. For return probes, both `arg0` and `arg1` contain the
>   return value. A non-zero value in the D variable `errno` indicates
>   system call failure.

Therefore in the clause

```
syscall::read:entry
{
    ...
}
```

, which corresponds to

```
ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);
```

, `arg0` would be the value of `fildes`, `arg1` would be the value of `buf` and `arg2` would be the value of `nbyte`.

The **type** of `arg0`, `arg1`, `arg2` etc. is always an [`int64_t`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28556/glgay.html#glghr), regardless of the types of the arguments that they represent.  This is enough for scalar quantities, but for a structure dtrace(1) needs to understand types.  It's possible to cast arguments, e.g.

```
((struct mystruct *)(arg0))->my_member
```

but this is irritating.  Sometimes, but not always, DTrace knows the types of the arguments themselves and allows them to be described using the notation `args[0]`, `args[1]` etc.;  thus under certain circumstances I could instead write the much more convenient

```
args[0]->my_member
```

For the syscall provider, DTrace *doesn't* know the arguments' types, which is why you see

```
# dtrace -lv -n syscall::read:entry
    ...
    Argument Types
        None

#
```

and why

```
dtrace -n 'syscall::read:entry {trace(args[0])}'
```

is not valid.

For the io provider, however, DTrace *does* know the arguments' types, e.g.

```
# dtrace -lv -n io:::start
    ... 
    Argument Types
        args[0]: bufinfo_t *
        args[1]: devinfo_t *
        args[2]: fileinfo_t *

#
```

By reading the [documentation for the io provider](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28556/gkzzf.html#scrolltoc) one can see that the definition of a `bufinfo_t` includes

```
typedef struct bufinfo {
    ...
    size_t b_bcount;                /* number of bytes */
    ...
} bufinfo_t;
```

and this allows one to write, e.g.

```
dtrace -n 'io:::start {trace(args[0]->b_bcount)}'.
```

Finally, you mention `fds[]`.  As I explained [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20846145/1579636), the type of `fds[n]` is `fileinfo_t *`.

I recommend that you follow this [introduction](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/DTrace/Introduction).

Answer (score 0):

How about `man 2 read`? On Mac OS, I get this:

```
READ(2)                     BSD System Calls Manual                    READ(2)

NAME
     pread, read, readv -- read input

LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

SYNOPSIS
     #include <sys/types.h>
     #include <sys/uio.h>
     #include <unistd.h>

     ssize_t
     pread(int d, void *buf, size_t nbyte, off_t offset);

     ssize_t
     read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);

     ssize_t
     readv(int d, const struct iovec *iov, int iovcnt);
...
```

This will obviously only work for the `syscall` provider, however.

Comment: I can't see .would you tell more detail?

Comment: The probes that match "`syscall:::entry`" (in your case, `syscall::read:entry`) mark the entry points to system calls. The `man` pages provide a list of arguments which are supplied to every system call. As you can see above, the arguments for `read()` are an `int` (file descriptor to read from), a `void *` (buffer to read data into), and a `size_t` (the unsigned integer number of bytes we wish to read). This will only work for system calls though, not arbitrary DTrace probes, since `man` doesn't typically provide documentation for kernel internals, etc.